# Das Quiz / Der Quiz

Tags: dialect, regional, article

Der Duden sagt eindeutig *Das Quiz*. Aber ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, *Der Quiz* war (zumindest im Osten) auch in Gebrauch. Ist das regional, oder hat sich das so weiterentwickelt oder ist das Dialekt? Die [ngram-Statistik](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=der%20Quiz,das%20Quiz&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=) zeigt leider keine regionale Verteilung über die Zeit.

Comment: Die meisten Treffer für _der Quiz_ sind Fälle wie „in der Quiz-Show“, „Auswahl der Quiz-Karten“ usw. Insofern kann man wenig aus der Statistik schließen.

Comment: Die Treffer kann man unten auf der Seite einsehen.

Comment: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=der+Quiz%2C%5Bder+Quiz+-%5D&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share= Jetzt verstehen wir, warum die Differenzmenge in der Mathematik doch Sinn macht ;) (Auch wenn das Ergebnis mit Sicherheit immer noch verfälscht ist. - Ich würde sagen, "der Quiz" konvergiert gegen null.)

Answer (score 1):

Ich bin kein Sprachforscher, aber meine Vermutung ist, dass hierbei die jeweils gängigste Übersetzung des englischen Begriffes eine Rolle spielt. So würde man heute "quiz" vermutlich mit "das Ratespiel" übersetzen, daher wäre "das Quiz" richtig. Früher hätte man vermutlich klassisch, in Anlehnung an die Schulprüfungen, "der Test" übersetzt und schon wäre "der Quiz" korrekt.

Man könnte das ja durchaus als Regionalismus bezeichnen -- Übersetzer richten sich zwecks besserer Verständlichkeit auch zum großen Teil nach der Ideologie und nach den gängigen Assoziationen, insofern dürfte sich eine DDR-Übersetzung von einer BRD-Übersetzung durchaus deutlich unterscheiden und dementsprechend auch Abweichungen im Sprachgebrauch nach sich ziehen.